# Trying to make the navbar width 100% to fit nav items on one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

For some reason my navbar is not becoming 100% width. I tried to make `.main-header` 100% width but still not sure what the problem. **The reason to make the navbar 100% is for all the nav items fit on one line.** Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is what the navbar looks like on the machine
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X1WO.jpg

**HTML**

```css
**Css**

/* Navigation */
.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo-name {   
  margin-left: 1%;  
  background-color: red;
}    
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0.3em;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
<!--<h1 class="logo-name"><li><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></li></h1>-->  
  <h1 class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></h1>

  <nav class="main-nav">
    <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
<!--<li><a href="#">FREE QUOTE</a></li>-->    
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Just created a fiddle with your code.
https://jsfiddle.net/k87qzvh7/ .
Have a look. Its taking the full width. Can you tell me what the issue?
Are you talking about the little space on the left and right ?

Comment: Are you looking for logo in single line ?

Comment: Here is what it looks like http://imgur.com/a/za9LH I want the purple navbar to be full width of screen @mechanicals

Comment: if you have done this.
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
} and it still doesn't work. then there must be other parent elements which are taking up that space.

Comment: Yes! You're right. The header is inside another div which was causing the problem thanks! @mechanicals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `body` take `8px` margin, thats why your navbar is not fullwifth. So add `margin:0` in your body tag. Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/XgmegE

```
body{
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably all you need is the padding and margin for html and body to be set to zero. You may want to consider using a generic reset like [this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [this](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

```css
/* Navigation */
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100vw;
}

.logo-name {
  margin-left: 1%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0.3em;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <!--        <h1 class="logo-name"><li><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></li></h1>
         -->
  <h1 class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></h1>

  <nav class="main-nav">
    <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <!--                    <li><a href="#">FREE QUOTE</a></li>
 -->
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the container wasn't full width. And the list items were also too small. Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/praedictus/pen/zzvpez

```
/* Navigation */

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo-name {   
  margin-left: 1%;  
  background-color: red;
}    
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0.3em;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
```